# Reading a string of data (with a particular format) into a list, in Python

Tags: python, windows, string, list

Say I have a file which contains one line of data formatted like this:

```
"THESE","ARE","WORDS","AND","I","NEED","THEM","IN","A","LIST"
```

(Of course, in reality the file is much larger.)

Is there an easy, short way to take this data and read it into a list which would print thus...

```
["THESE", "ARE", "WORDS", "AND", "I", "NEED", "THEM", "IN", "A", "LIST"]
```

...?

I'm just wondering, because although it's certainly possible to iterate over every character in the file working out what it means and where it belongs, I find that irritating, and I'm sure there's some way of doing it more simply. I just don't know of the methods.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

split and strip

```
a='"THESE","ARE","WORDS","AND","I","NEED","THEM","IN","A","LIST"'
[i.strip('"') for i in a.split(",")]
['THESE', 'ARE', 'WORDS', 'AND', 'I', 'NEED', 'THEM', 'IN', 'A', 'LIST']
```

Note that there is no semantic difference between ' and ".

**Update:** I do support the answer by @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams for any situation where you need to accept  cases like these:

```
a=r""""And",'b',"W,B'" """  
ast.literal_eval(a)    # gives the expected and correct
('And', 'b', "W,B'")
```

while the split/strip solution I suggested gives

```
['And', "'b'", 'W', 'B\'" ']
```

Comment: Ah. There we go. Big help, I didn't really know of the strip() or split() functions' uses until this thread. Thanks.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, thank you for spotting the missing comma.

Answer (score 3):

```
import StringIO
import csv

s = '"THESE","ARE","WORDS","AND","I","NEED","THEM","IN","A","LIST"'
result = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(s)).next()
```

returns

```
['THESE', 'ARE', 'WORDS', 'AND', 'I', 'NEED', 'THEM', 'IN', 'A', 'LIST']
```

Comment: That's actually a good point, I didn't realise that file was effectively in CSV format. Thanks!

Comment: Yup - this would have been my answer - `csv` makes perfect sense

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind a *tiny* bit of post-processing...

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('"THESE","ARE","WORDS","AND","I","NEED","THEM","IN","A","LIST"')
('THESE', 'ARE', 'WORDS', 'AND', 'I', 'NEED', 'THEM', 'IN', 'A', 'LIST')
```

Comment: Why `ast` for a `str.split` operation?

Comment: This is _quite_ elegant, but I'll wait for some more answers to come up as well just to see!

Comment: +1. My answer was accepted but this is the full solution for more general cases.

Answer (score 1):

Why not `split'?

```
>>> '"THESE","ARE","WORDS","AND","I","NEED","THEM","IN","A","LIST"'.split(',')
['"THESE"', '"ARE"', '"WORDS"', '"AND"', '"I"', '"NEED"', '"THEM"', '"IN"', '"A"', '"LIST"']
```

OR

```
>>> [s.strip('"') for s in '"THESE","ARE","WORDS","AND","I","NEED","THEM","IN","A","LIST"'.split(',')]
['THESE', 'ARE', 'WORDS', 'AND', 'I', 'NEED', 'THEM', 'IN', 'A', 'LIST']
```

OR

```
>>> map(lambda s: s.strip('"'), '"THESE","ARE","WORDS","AND","I","NEED","THEM","IN","A","LIST"'.split(','))
['THESE', 'ARE', 'WORDS', 'AND', 'I', 'NEED', 'THEM', 'IN', 'A', 'LIST']
```

Comment: Because each string in the list needs to exclude the double-quotes.

Comment: Same answer as Johan, so I'll give you both the credit. Thanks!

Comment: Ahh! Didn't see that before. Alternative version is up

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a hack, but it looks similar to JSON

```
import json
print json.parse('[' + your_line_here + ']')
```